# Facebook: Determine if User is Fan (likes page)

Tags: facebook

Is there a way to determine if the current user is a fan (now: likes the page) using facebook connect?

I know this is possible in the REST api, but I would like to be able to just use connect instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to log the user in with Facebook connect and the Javascript SDK.

Then in Javascript you can use FB.api to call the Graph API.

```
FB.api('/me/likes');
```

This requires the `user_likes` permission to be granted when they login.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user

Answer (score 2):

I'd rather use FQL:
SELECT page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid=me() and page_id=114342017879

If the query returns an empty array, then your user is not fan.
If it returns the page id in an array, then he's fan:

```
[
    {
        "page_id": "114342017879"
    }
]
```

**Webservice url:**

https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT+page_id+FROM+page_fan+WHERE+uid%3Dme%28%29+and+page_id%3D114342017879